# EF Table with inheritace but not Abstract?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to make three table:

1. `Tasks` - that table store informations as Ids, Names, Priority of tasks
2. `TakenTasks` - in this table we store user's ID that take tasks with DateTime
3. `EndedTasks` - Task that end with DateTime of end

My question is, how to make in `EntityFramework Core` table `TakenTasks` and `EndedTasks` have the same propertys mapped to `Tasks` table without rewriteing code for Ids of tasks, name of tasks etc?

`Tasks` table can be build based on `abstract Task` class because i want to have object of `Task` in list. What is the best solution for scenerio as i mentioned above?

```
public class Task 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Priority Priority { get; set; }
}

public class TakenTask 
{
    string UserId { get; set; }
    DateTime DateOfTaken { get; set; }
}

public class EndedTask 
{
    DateTime DateOfEnd { get; set; }
}
```

How to store information from `Task` in `TakenTask` and `EndedTask` withotu rewriting propertys from `Task` and have 3 tables ?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better to normalize the 3 table, and just use 1 table with a flag to indicate its taken or ended

Comment: But what is better? What is normally use in real world enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to duplicate the columns in three tables, use a foreign key from `TakenTasks` and `EndedTasks` to `Task` and you can create a `public virtual Task ParentTask{ get; set; }` in both `TakenTasks` and `EndedTasks` so you can access the Task properties

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 tables:

1. `Task`
2. `Assign`

In `Task` should have

```
int Id { get; set; }
string Name { get; set; }
Priority Priority { get; set; }
Status Status { get; set; }
```

In `Assign` should have

```
int TaskId { get; set; }
int UserNameId { get; set; }
DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
DateTime EndDate { get; set; }`
```

Hope this help